# I can SystemOpen but I can't Import an online file (Internet and Intranet)

Tags: import

Thank you MarcoB and Pickett.

I am currently using the Mathematica trial version on my laptop since my company's enterprise version will take 2 more weeks to setup because there are a lot of hoops to jump through for security reasons. In addition, my laptop uses PowerBroker for Windows. Therefore, I don't know if that has anything to do with my following problem.

```
Import["http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/NO2.dat", "Table"]
```

> FetchURL::httperr: The request to URL http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/NO2.dat was not successful. The server returned the HTTP status code 404 ("Not Found").
>
> $Failed

When I tried to open the file with the SystemOpen command, I don't have any problem seeing the data on the browser.

```
SystemOpen["http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/NO2.dat"]
```

The browser displays the following: (I am only pasting 5 lines of output)

> ```
> 3.71844   7.6912   9.2    4.8 -0.1    74.4    20  600
>
> 3.10009   7.69894  6.4    3.5 -0.3    56      14  196
>
> 3.31419   4.81218 -3.7    0.9 -0.1    281.3   4   513
>
> 4.38826   6.95177 -7.2    1.7  1.2    74      23  143
>
> 4.3464    7.51806 -1.3    2.6 -0.1    65      11  115
> ```

Comment: I can't see anything clearly wrong with what you are doing. Could you try to download the log file separately from your browser and importing the data into *Mathematica* from the local copy, just to see that `Import` can deal with it? Also, try to import this smaller data file from [StatLib at Carnegie-Mellon](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/): `Import["http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/NO2.dat", "Table"]`. I have just tried on my end, and it works fine; this way we can check that everything is fine with how *Mathematica* accesses the Internet on your side.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You have more than 10 reputation now, so please post the real URLs. Can't debug this without a reproducible example.

Comment: The updated code works on my machine. If the problem persists, I might guess, it either has to do with the trial version or the security hurdles in your network that you mentioned.